# Test Fallback method using sping-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, timeout, resilience4j

```
public String getAlbumList() {
    CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("circuitbreaker");
    String url = "http://localhost:1234/not-real";
    
    return circuitBreaker.run(() -> restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class), 
      throwable -> getDefaultAlbumList());
}
```

Assume this is my code and "getDefaultAlbumList()" is returning some string "ABCD", and let say my "restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class)" is going to call some URL which may take more than 5 second, now point is

I want to test that fallback method, how do i test it, how do i mock so that my controller return fallback response.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are trying out the example from here: [Quick Guide to Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-circuit-breaker). So, I copied their service and I introduced a method to pass a null URL. Then I created a test in a spring boot project that verifies if the string value that returns is the fallback string.

```
@Service
public class AlbumService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    @Autowired
    private CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;
    public String getAlbumList() {
        return getAlbumList("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums");
    }
    public String getAlbumList(String url) {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("circuitbreaker");
        return circuitBreaker.run(() -> restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class),
                throwable -> getDefaultAlbumList());
    }
    // fallback method that reads a default json file
    private String getDefaultAlbumList() {
        try {
            return new String(Files.readAllBytes(
                    Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("data/fallback-album-list.json").toURI())
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error occurred while reading the file", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then the unit test should test the fallback default json string.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, properties = {"server.port=0"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext
class AlbumServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    AlbumService albumService;
    @Test
    void getAlbumListFallBack() {
        String result = albumService.getAlbumList(null);
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertTrue(result.length() > 0);
        assertEquals(
                "[\n" +
                        "  {\n" +
                        "    \"userId\": 1,\n" +
                        "    \"id\": 1,\n" +
                        "    \"title\": \"quidem molestiae enim\"\n" +
                        "  },\n" +
                        "  {\n" +
                        "    \"userId\": 1,\n" +
                        "    \"id\": 2,\n" +
                        "    \"title\": \"sunt qui excepturi placeat culpa\"\n" +
                        "  }\n" +
                        "]",
                result);
    }
}
```